# How to assign a value to a variable from MS Access

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I'm using an admin privilege system from my database, the max level is "3".
So when a user clicks login, at the corner of the program he can see his admin level.
I wanted to assign this to a variable but I'm always getting errors.

```cs
adp.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select dastresi from Users where username = '" + username+"'";
```

(dastresi means access level)

Comment: `I'm always getting errors.` what errors? Where do you *execute* the query? In any case, this is extremely dangerous code that leaves you wide open to SQL injection. Imagine what would happen if someone entered `'; drop table Users;--` as a user name. Check [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/). This code will fail in normal operation too, eg if a username contains `'`, eg `O'Reily`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Well I'm a very beginner, so I am just learning the basics of it. When I start the project I'm seeing this:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

The line that contains error:
label4.Text = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();

Comment: Please update the question with this info, rather than adding it as a comment.

Comment: label4.Text = dataGridView2.SelectedCells [0] .Value.ToString (); If data not exist how you check this?